# pyqgis error messages using PYCHARM

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, python-2.7, pycharm

I use pyqgis in standalone app using python 2.7 in windows 10.

I have create some scripts using python idle and  work fine without some errors or messages.

Now I try to use pyqgis using pycharm editor with the some scripts where I have run it before in python editor.

in the pycharm that scripts work again,I get correct outputs but in the pycharm show me some errors messages and in the final show crashed error python but my output is correct.

like this :

```
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
ERROR: Opening of authentication db FAILED
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QPSQL7 QPSQL QODBC3 QODBC
WARNING: Auth db query exec() FAILED
QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
ERROR: Opening of authentication db FAILED

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) (and 255)
```

I don't get exit code 0 I get it `-1073741819 (0xC0000005)` and `255`.

any idea why I take that error messages in pycharm and not in python editor ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935892/python-qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded

Comment: @StephenRauch I don't have `qsqlmysql4.dll` in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\` and I don't  have `sqldrivers`,how to fix that without destroy my system ?